# "Unresolved class 'PlaceHolderFragment'"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I get an error in my layout file:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <!-- Some stuff here -->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and it gives me an error at this line:

```
tools:context="com.myapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
```

and the error reads:

> Unresolved class 'PlaceHolderFragment'
>   Valid resource references
>   inside Android XML files.

I can build my app and run it, and I haven't found anything that helps to resolve my error here on Stackoverflow, and elsewhere. Anyone that knows why I get this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can safely remove `tools:context` entry from that XML as this is only for your Android Studio to know what is in the context of that layout (here's [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html) for supported `tools:...` tags), however you should definitely avoid having fragments as inner class of Activities (and as inner class in general) as this will cause you more troubles nonetheless, therefore I strongly suggest refactoring your code and separating your `PlaceholderFragment` from activity class code completely.

Comment: Thanks, Marcin! I have already refactored and moved my PlaceholderFragment to a separate class, that's probably why I noticed the error now. Will accept this answer when SO lets me!